# Writing typescript type defintions for jquery extensions

Tags: jquery, typescript, typescript-typings

I've some `jquery` extensions written in javascript. They are accessed like:

```
var myNumber = $.myStaticFunction(myString);    
var myObject = $('selector').myElementFunction(myString);
```

To use this functions in the typescript part, I can change the index.d.ts of jQuery:

```
interface JQuery<TElement extends Node = HTMLElement> extends Iterable<TElement> {

  ...
  myElementFunction: (sr:string) => {foo:number, bar:string};
  ...

interface JQueryStatic<TElement extends Node = HTMLElement> {        
  ...
  myStaticFunction: (sr:string) => number;
  ...
```

So I know this is the ugliest way to change directly the index.d.ts! I think I've to write a seperate myextension.d.ts. How does I've to write the defintion file for jquery extensions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change existing definition files. Typescript supports [interface mering](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html). You can just define your `myextension.d.ts` and use `///` reference.

```
// myextension.d.ts
interface JQuery<TElement extends Node = HTMLElement> extends Iterable<TElement> {
    myElementFunction: (sr: string) => { foo: number, bar: string };
}

interface JQueryStatic<TElement extends Node = HTMLElement> {
    myStaticFunction: (sr: string) => number;
}


//usage.ts
/// <reference path="myextension.d.ts" />
var myNumber = $.myStaticFunction("myString");    
var myObject = $('selector').myElementFunction("myString");
```